# Proper formatting when adding dynamic content in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to dynamically add some content to a list of checkboxes in an collapsible `<li>` item in jQuery Mobile. I cannot get the proper formatting with the nice rounded corners and the grouped items. It gets even worse when I add other elements at the leaf level.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xg8Ge/) is an example that shows the problem (add jquery and jquerymobile scripts and CSS in the header obviously):

```
<body> 
 <div data-role="page" id="page">
  <ul id="listList" data-role="listview">
   <li id="list1" data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>list 1</h3>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="fs1">
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" /><label for="cb1">text</label></fieldset></div></li>
   <li id="list2" data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>list 2</h3>
     <p>here comes another list of checkboxes...</p></li></ul>
 <input type="button" onclick="addCheckbox();" value="add a checkbox to list1" /></div>
</body>
<script>
 function addCheckbox() {
   $("#list1 fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" /><label for="cb2">More text</label>');
 }
</script>
```

I tried to add `.page()` after the call to `append()`but it did not work properly though a bit better.

Beyond my example, the generic question is how to dynamically append content to the DOM tree after jQuery Mobile has played around with the DOM structure. I believe there exists a function that "jquerymobilizes" part of the tree but I cannot find it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

*EDIT: In short, I am trying to dynamically add elements into one `<li>`element of the `listview` and not trying to add elements to the list itself. Refreshing the `listview` does not seemt o help here.*

*EDIT 2: I am getting a bit closer as I found the `.trigger("create")` function that can be chained to `.append()` (cf [JQM FAQ](http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html)). With the following script it works slightly better though the `data-role="controlgroup"` does not provide the right formatting with nice rounded boxes.*

```
$("#list1 fieldset").append('<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" /><label for="cb2">More text</label>').trigger("create");
```

I will post the full answer if I get there at some point.

EDIT 3: Here is my example illustrated in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xg8Ge/)

Comment: PS: I am also wondering why the checkbox seems disabled and the collapsible items are not collapsed by default in my the example, but this is secondary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I could answer my own question so here is what I got:

- to dynamically add elements in jQuery Mobile use `.trigger("create")` (cf. [jQuery Mobile FAQ](http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html))
- to add them to the collapsible part of a collapsible element add it to `div.ui-collapsible-content` or create a `div` container within the collapsible part *ex ante* so you add the content directly there
- to get the nice rendering of grouped checkboxes, you should add all the checkboxes at once (I could not get the sleek rounded corners when I added them sequentially

So here is my final script that does what I needed:

```
$("#list1 div[data-role='fieldcontain']").append('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">'
    +'<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" /><label for="cb1">text</label>'
    +'<input type="checkbox" id="cb2" /><label for="cb2">More text</label></fieldset>'
    +'<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete">Delete</a>')
    .trigger("create");
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

This problem is because of , after you append the dynamic content to listview , the jquery mobile classes may not applying for your listview . so try any of the following

```
$('#listList').listview('refresh');   //which refresh your list view
$('#listList').listview('refresh',true);   //which rebuilds the listview with your new content
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I tried to explain in another comment, I do not add elements to the list view but append items to the collapsible part of one element of the div. Refreshing the listview does not seem to be of any help here.

Comment: @Mad Echet : I think your onclick event is not firing on the function " addCheckbox() " . Can you check this by placing alert in first line of your function code ... You can check your example here [link] http://jsfiddle.net/reddyprasad321/wECQx/5/

Comment: thanks for taking a look, I don't quite know why the event is not firing in your example (I am not familiar with jsfiddle) but firing was not the problem for me (the text was properly added but the formatting was missing). I will try to post a working example in jsfiddle but you can find my solution in my answer.

Comment: @Mad Echet : yah , please post the working example in jsfiddle and post the same link here as answer... so that any one got same problem , can get easily trace out with that live example....

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xg8Ge/ is the problem I exposed and http://jsfiddle.net/hbbvM the working example (also available in my main post and my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I follow. Are you looking more for how to apply the appropriate style. If this is the case you will need to use:

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

This would be after you have appended new items to your list.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that jquery mobile creates a series of containers and reorganizes the elements when the page is loaded. When I dynamically add new jquery elements (in this case input checkboxes and their labels), the reorganization never happens, hence the ugly presentation. Refresh works on a list view but in my example, the problem comes from the input checkboxes, I do not add any item to the list but append items to the collapsible part of one item in the list.