# Dynamically adding content to panel listview with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, jquery-mobile

I am working on a django powered SPA app thats primary interface is powered by jquery mobile.

I have a single panel. My end goal is to have this panel dynamically updated depending on the link the user clicks to open it.

The panel starts blank:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="properties_panel" data-display="overlay" data-position="right" data-position-fixed=true>
</div>
```

However, when certain links are clicked, I would like to load external html files using AJAX to update the content of the panel:

```
var panel_text;
var menu_item_selector = $.get( "{% static 'elements/menu_preferences_elements.html' %}", function() {
        panel_text = menu_item_selector['responseText'];
    })
    .done(function() {

    })
    .fail(function() {

    })
    .always(function() {

});
```

Now, the ajax file is successfully fetched and loaded, however, my goal is to display the content as a jquery mobile element (in this case a list view). However, the content is displaying as a normal list, not as a listview.

Contents of menu_preferences_elements.html:

```
<div class="editing_tools_section shadow">
    <div class="editing_tools_heading ui-btn ui-icon-minus ui-btn-icon-right ui-nodisc-icon">Search for menu item</div>
    <div class="editing_tools_item">Use the search box below to search for a menu item.</div>
    <div class="editing_tools_item grey_bg">
        <ul id="menu_item_list" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-icon="false" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search for menu item..." data-inset="true">

             <script>
                menu_database().each(function(record){
                    document.write("<li><a href='#'  data-elementid='"+record.Item_Id+"'>"+record.Name+"</a></li>");
                });
            </script>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I put the contents of that external html file directly into the panel, it functions 100% as expected. However, when I dynamically add it, it doesn't treat it as jquery mobile content, and instead renders it as a plain list.

Here is the jquery onclick listener:

```
$(".editing_tools_section").on('click','.editing_tools_item', function(){

    $("#properties_panel").html(panel_text);

    $("#properties_panel").trigger('updatelayout');
    $("#properties_panel").panel("open");

 });
```

Is there a way to make the content display correctly as a filterable jquery mobile listview?

EDIT:

Fixed using the create method:

```
 $("#properties_panel").trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try triggering the `create` method on the div?

```
$(".editing_tools_section").on('click','.editing_tools_item', function(){

    $("#properties_panel").html(panel_text);

    $("#properties_panel").trigger('updatelayout');
    $("#properties_panel").trigger('create');
    $("#properties_panel").panel("open");

 });
```

The accepted answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456809/proper-formatting-when-adding-dynamic-content-in-jquery-mobile) here on SO, talks about this in more detail.